# Mobile Device Management iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a simple yet clear question:

Is it possible to **launch** an iOS app remotely (via a server) **using the** [Mobile Device Management protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/1-Introduction/Introduction.html) provided by Apple (assuming this app is used through an Enterprise account)?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question. If it is, please clarify what the programming issue is. If not, please delete and consider posting at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi rmaddy, it will definitely become a programming question if the answer to the initial one is yes :)

Answer (score 0):

short Answer no. you can use something can [testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and [hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net) to
or read this https://support.apple.com/en-ca/business

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I know both TestFlight and HockeyApp - very useful third party to deploy your application to beta testers and collect crash reports etc. But how could one of those allow you to launch remotely an app in development?

Comment: Try the 3rd link

Comment: Could you be more specific as the third link point to several different documentations?